# Create express route to match wildcard page but no pages under it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using wildcard-subdomains to handle wildcard subdomains in my express app, so something like `subdomain.localhost:3000` would enter the router as `/s/subdomain/`.

I want to match the main index url of any subdomain, but none of the pages under it.

Essentially, I want a route that would match `/s/subdomain/` but not  `/s/subdomain/page/` or `/s/subdomain/page` (for clarity, "subdomain" is just a placeholder for any wildcard domain)

This is simple to do in regular regex, but I am unable to use the dot modifier due to express using path-to-regexp. It would be possible for me to generate a router for each user, but I would really like to use something cleaner if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dang, i'm pretty stupid. `/s/:target/` works perfectly fine, and creates a neat little target parameter to make things a bit easier. I was totally overcomplicating things by trying to use regex.